# How to handle 'Cannot connect to Gmail' errors?

Tags: google-apps-script

I've created a script to send SMS notifications once important message is received (in accordance with [this](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/gmail_filter_sms) tutorial).
But quite often I receive notifications, that script failed to finish successfully. Error message is `Cannot connect to Gmail (line 13)`, line 13 is:

```
var threads = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName('SMS').getThreads();
```

How should I handle it? I.e. just to stop execution and wait for next run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A nice way would be to wrap your code around in a while loop and a try catch block and try until the operation is successful. 
Something like ...

```
var retryCount = 0; 
var success = false ; 

while (!success & retryCount++ <=5 ){
  try{
    var threads = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName('SMS').getThreads();
    // Other code here 

    success = true; 
  }catch(ex){ 
    Logger.log(ex);
  }
  Utilities.sleep(1000);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Should I add pause somehow between each attempt?

Comment: Yes, thats a good idea too. I've edited my answer to incorporate a sleep

Answer (score 0):

why not a try/catch structure ? If you followed the tuto you have a spreadsheet available to log errors and to check if execution was complete or not so you can decide what to do.